# Can a loose SATA connection cause the drive to click

Tags: hard-drive, sata

My SATA drive was clicking and I couldn't access it. I found that the SATA connection was a little loose so I pushed it back in. The drive stopped clicking and I was able to access the data. Could the loose connection have been the reason it was malfunctioning?

Comment: you'd better replace the cable; unstable power will lead to damage to the hard disk.

Comment: Cable is fine it just wasn't pushed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I can imagine this being connected is if power part of your SATA connection was not fully engaged. This would cause less than full power to be transfered to drive and it could cause "clicks" as drive spins up and then down because lack of power.

If just data connection was disconnected, I do not think that this was reason nor fix.

Answer (score 3):

Usually clicking means that the drive is near failure. I would IMMEDIATELY copy everything to a back up device and then have it checked out.

Comment: yes. in exact, mechanical failure. either the motor or the disk is probably damaged.